# Worksheet_Calculate: Multiple targets and values

Tags: excel, vba

How can I make this change other line colors based on other cell values and ranges? Not only B37 but, for example, b38 with a range of >=88 clr vbGreen and <88 clr vbRed for Straight Connector 2. Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim v, clr As Long

    v = Me.Range("B37").value
    If not isnumeric(v) or len(v) = 0 then exit sub

    If v < 0.95 Then
        clr = vbRed
    ElseIf v >= 0.95 And v < 1 Then
        clr = vbGreen
    Else
        clr = vbYellow
    End If
    Me.Shapes("Straight Connector 1").Line.ForeColor.RGB = clr
End Sub
```

Comment: since all your conditions are specific, you will have to duplicate what you have and change the needed variables. So you will have two (or more) blocks of code inside the change event. Each with the specific conditions needed. Or to make it easier, you can build a table with your conditions and objects and have the code loop through the table to set the colors of the Connector shapes.

Comment: I am attempting to do that and i get an error with `Dim v, clr As long` being duplicated

Comment: As you may have guessed, I'm new to VBA and it get the concept but not the details. Not sure how to create the table you suggest either, but that seems like the way to go.

Comment: Tim has already answered this on your other Q

Comment: @SackOvergrowth - the Dim statements only need to be declared once. the variables can be used over and over again. For the table, create a table on a worksheet with 3 columns. Range, Color and Connector. For color write a formula against the range to determine the color. Then loop through this table and fill each connector with the appropriate color from the table, using the `Connector` and `Color` column. For more info, lookup `loop through listobject rows in vba`.

Comment: @Scott how is this any different to the OP's other Q? (Not trying to be rude, I would like to know why you think this is worth reopening)

Comment: @chrisneilsen - I thought the difference in the limits warranted re-opening. Perhaps I didn't pay deep enough attention to all the comments though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This Works!**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    SetLineColor1 Me.Range("B37"), Me.Shapes("Line 1")
    SetLineColor2 Me.Range("D35"), Me.Shapes("Line 2")
End Sub

Sub SetLineColor1(c As Range, ln As Shape)
    Dim v, clr As Long

    v = c.Value
    If Not IsNumeric(v) Or Len(v) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    If v < 0.95 Then
        clr = vbRed
    ElseIf v >= 0.95 And v < 1 Then
        clr = vbGreen
    Else
        clr = vbYellow
    End If
    ln.Line.ForeColor.RGB = clr
End Sub
Sub SetLineColor2(c As Range, ln As Shape)
    Dim v, clr As Long

    v = c.Value
    If Not IsNumeric(v) Or Len(v) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    If v < 88 Then
        clr = vbRed
    ElseIf v >= 88 And v < 100 Then
        clr = vbGreen
    Else
        clr = vbYellow
    End If
    ln.Line.ForeColor.RGB = clr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in your other post: add two additional parameters to your SetLineColor method -

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    SetLineColor Me.Range("B37"), Me.Shapes("Line 1"), 0.95, 1
    SetLineColor Me.Range("D35"), Me.Shapes("Line 2"), 88, 100
End Sub

Sub SetLineColor(c As Range, ln As Shape, limit1 As Double, limit2 As Double)
    Dim v, clr As Long

    v = c.Value
    If Not IsNumeric(v) Or Len(v) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    If v < limit1 Then
        clr = vbRed
    ElseIf v >= limit1 And v < limit2 Then
        clr = vbGreen
    Else
        clr = vbYellow
    End If
    ln.Line.ForeColor.RGB = clr
End Sub
```